# how to retrieve the multiple data from sqlite database in ionic when net connection is none

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I want  to retrieve the multiple data from sqlite database in ionic when navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE and also i want to insert the multiple data in databse

Comment: what does sqlite database operation have do with your device network status ? Is it causing issues?

Comment: then what is the issue??